# SystemLog Logger doesn't work in LibComponentLogging?

Tags: iphone

I used *LibComponentLogging* for my base error logging mechanism in IPhone application. but it doesn't work properly with systemlog after deploying to the device.

Please help me on this issue.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot reconfigure syslog on the iPhone, please make sure that you've set _LCLSystemLog_LastASLLogLevelToUse to ASL_LEVEL_NOTICE in your LCLSystemLogConfig.h file. Otherwise you will only see warnings, errors, and above, but no info or debug messages.

The syslog-based log messages are sent to your iPhone's system log. You can view the iPhone's system log when you open the Organizer window in Xcode and select the Console view for your iPhone.

If you want to view the log messages from your iPhone on your Mac, then I would recommend the logging back-end for Florent's NSLogger: https://github.com/aharren/LibComponentLogging-NSLogger